# How close have we come to passing the Turing Test?

Tags: turing-test

The Turing Test has been the classic test of artificial intelligence for a while now. The concept is deceptively simple - to trick a human into thinking it is another human on the other end of a conversation line, not a computer - but from what I've read, it has turned out to be very difficult in practice.

How close have we gotten to tricking a human in the Turing Test? With things like chat bots, Siri, and incredibly powerful computers, I'm thinking we're getting pretty close. If we're pretty far, why are we so far? What is the main problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one has attempted to make a system that could pass a serious Turing test. All the systems that are claimed to have "passed" Turing tests have done so with low success rates simulating "special" people.  Even relatively sophisticated systems like Siri and learning systems like [Cleverbot](http://www.cleverbot.com) are trivially stumped.

To pass a real Turing test, you would both have to create a human-level AGI and equip it with the specialized ability to deceive people about itself convincingly (of course, that might come automatically with the human-level AGI).  We don't really know how to create a human-level AGI and available hardware appears to be orders of magnitude short of what is required.  Even if we were to develop the AGI, it wouldn't necessarily be useful to enable/equip/motivate? it to have the deception abilities required for the Turing test.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know I think this is the closest we've come:

http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-27762088

They simulated a 13 year old Ukrainian child in an online chat and convinced 33% of the judges that it was human. But even then the test was in favor of the bot. To my knowledge I don't think an AI has passed a turing test straight up.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that "pornbots" regularly pass the Turing Test in regards to the general public *(although, clearly, the judgement of those being tricked is weakened by hormonal imperatives.)*

http://boingboing.net/2004/07/27/elizabot-passes-sexc.html

http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/pornbots-sexual-barbies-of-the-future/